# Soldered connection to composite video is not outputting video | Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: composite-video

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I'm trying to output video from the pads on the back of the PCB, how ever it is not outputting video. I've tested the video with a raspberry pi zero and the video outputted fine. Its just not working with my Pi 3 Model B. 
When typing:

```
tvservice -s
```

It outputs:

```
state 0x40001 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced
```

The config.txt does not have:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

So it is commented out and not being read, another attempt trying to get it to work I added:

```
hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1
```

to the config.txt also. I need to have the video SOLDERED to the Raspberry Pi! Please help, I've tried everything and nothing is working.

EDIT:
The composite display is connected to PP24 on the back of the Pi

Comment: to rule out the obvious is anything connected or plgged into the HDMI?

Comment: The Pi3 is not designed to have video soldered - who knows what you connected where?

Comment: There is nothing in the HDMI plug... And the Pi3 must of had intentions of people soldering video to it, why would PP24 be there? I have my screen connected to PP24.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, but did you connect ground?

Comment: Yes, I did, its connected to PP06

Comment: Does it work if you connect properly using a plug? `PP24` is unlikely to be composite video.